# Using plots as objects in python (jupyter lab)?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-lab

I just started switching from R to python, and have been a bit confused by the way plots are handled.

In R, I would generate a scatter plot this way: 
`myPlot <- ggplot(myData, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point()`. myPlot will be treated as an object, I can save it, copy it, pass it, or just plot it later.

However, in python I couldn't figure out how to do it. For example, when I use:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'X': [1,2,3],
    'Y': [4,5,6]
})
ax = df.plot(kind="scatter", x='X', y='Y')
```

all I want to do here is to save the plot to an object, so that it can be easily plotted later without executing all the code again (it's easy to redo in this dummy case but my data is far more complicated)

It seems that I was able to save some information into "ax", as suggested online, but I couldn't figure out how to reproduce the plot with the object "ax".

Thank you so much~

Comment: What do you mean by "reproduce the plot"? Can you show the actual problem you face?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [visualization section](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html) of the pandas docs.

`ax` in your example indeed holds the plot object. Depending on your environment you can save it to a figure or display it inline.

The easiest way is just to `plt.show()`.

Comment: Note however that `ax` is by convention reserved for axis objects. Maybe have a look here: https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.00-introduction-to-matplotlib.html